# Upstart tracking wrong PID of Bluepill

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, bluepill

I have bluepill setup to monitor my delayed_job processes.

Using Ubuntu 12.04.

I am starting and monitoring the bluepill service itself using Ubuntu's `upstart`. My upstart config is below (`/etc/init/bluepill.conf`).

```
description "Start up the bluepill service"

start on runlevel [2]
stop on runlevel [016]

expect fork
exec sudo /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/<app_name>/bluepill load /home/deploy/websites/<app_name>/current/config/server/staging/delayed_job.bluepill

# Restart the process if it dies with a signal
# or exit code not given by the 'normal exit' stanza.
respawn
```

I have also tried with `expect daemon` instead of `expect fork`. I have also tried removing the `expect...` line completely.

When the machine boots, bluepill starts up fine.

```
$ ps aux | grep blue
root      1154  0.6  0.8 206416 17372 ?        Sl   21:19   0:00 bluepilld: <app_name>
```

The PID of the bluepill process is 1154 here. But `upstart` seems to be tracking the wrong PID.

```
$ initctl status bluepill
bluepill start/running, process 990
```

This is preventing the bluepill process from getting respawned if I forcefully kill bluepill using `kill -9`.

Moreover, I think because of the wrong PID being tracked, reboot / shutdown just hangs and I have to hard reset the machine every time.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, upstart tracks the wrong PID.  From looking at the *bluepill* source code, it uses the *daemons* gem to daemonize, which in turn forks twice.  So `expect daemon` in the upstart config *should* track the correct PID -- but you've already tried that.

If it is possible for you, you should run *bluepill* in the foreground, and not use any `expect` stanza at all in your upstart config.

From the *bluepill* documentation:

```
Bluepill.application("app_name", :foreground => true) do |app|
  # ...
end
```

will run *bluepill* in the foreground.